# S/Mime Attachment java

Tags: java, smime

I try to sign email with S/Mime protocol. It works fine with the body. But when I join an attachment to the email, the digital signature make the name of the email (and the extension) empty. So the email received is with an attachement "whitoutTitle.dat" instead of a "name.pdf" for example.  I use SMIMESignedGenerator from BCMail. 
The attachement is not modified. That is why I'm troubled.

```
// This attachment part loose the name after the digital signature
File partFile = new File(fileName);
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(partFile);
attachmentPart1.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
attachmentPart1.setFileName(partFile.getName());

// This attachment don't loose its name after the signature
attachmentPart2.setText(strinbBuilder.toString());
attachmentPart2.setFileName("name.txt");

multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart1);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart2);

mimemsg.setContent(multipart);

MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = mimemsg.getContent();

SMIMESignedGenerator generator = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
generator.addCertificates(getCertificateStore(smimeKey));
generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(getInfoGenerator(smimeKey));
MimeMultipart signedMimeMultipart = generator.generate(mimeBodyPart);
MimeBodyPart signedMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
signedMimeBodyPart.setContent(signedMimeMultipart);
```

Has anyone  had the same issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would most likely be very good if you also attach a [mcve] code along with your question. This way people can see for themselves if you're doing anything incorrectly. Just mentioning a class name without saying how you use it is most unhelpful.

Comment: Ok, I just modified my request. Thanks for advise

Comment: It's still incomplete, I'm afraid. Does `mimeBodyPart` contain anything relevant (I assume it does, because that's about the only part here that could do anything, it looks like)? Have you checked with different body parts?

Comment: Thanks for your help. mimeBodyPart  has 3 part :
-a body part, 
- the attachment whose name is lost (fill with setDatahandler and setFileName)
- another attachment made with text content whose name is not lost (fill with setText and setFileName)

Comment: I could only find [this exchange on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1333248/s-mime-signed-email-loses-attachment), but that doesn't give a whole lot of information on how to implement what you're trying to do. Since I'm no expect in this, I'll leave it to others to answer this proper.

Comment: Well, thanks for taking the time to try to help me. The link you refere to is not exactly my issue because i get the attachment. I just lose the name :-(

Comment: I can only suggest diving down into the internals with a debugger to see why it writes wrong things into an attachment file name. That's what I'd do here - at the end of the day, any name has to come from somewhere. It may so happen that this is because you override the file name in mime body part (doubt it though).

Comment: The first thing I did was to pass in debug mod but without success. I don't know if it is  an eclipse problem howerver I could not see the generate part step by step (the package is imported by maven). A solution is to import directly the class of the package directly in my project. Well, I'll try to do it because, I don't have any other idea right now.

Answer (score 0):

I found an explaination I can't really understand. In fact, the file name is sent "normally" but with the format in the header

```
Content-Disposition : attachment; filename*=Cp1252''newName.pdf .
```

If I don't set the file name, I have :

```
Content-Disposition : attachment; filename=oldName.pdf
```

(I needed to modify the name so I used the fileName setter). I cannot explain why but the "*=Cp1252''" part is the responsible of the absence of the name in the attachment but only after the message was signed (if not, I've got the good name). So my solution is to modify the name directly by :

```
attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "newName.pdf")
```

and it works !
It is not elegant but it is a solution.